# How to increase Items Quantity in Cart

Tags: php, session, cart

I want to increase the quantity of product when i click on add to cart multiple time but i does not increase its quantity remain same, someone help me to solve this problem. what do i code in blank else section

```
if(isset($_POST["submit1"]))
{
    if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
    {
        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");
        if(!in_array($_GET["product_id"], $item_array_id))
        {
            $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
            $item_array = array(
                'item_id'           =>  $_GET["product_id"],
                'item_name'         =>  $_POST["hidden_name"],
                'item_price'        =>  $_POST["hidden_price"],
                'item_quantity'     =>  $_POST["quantity"],
               'item_image'     =>  $_POST["hidden_image"],

            );
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
        }
        else
        {




        }
    }
    else
    {
        $item_array = array(
            'item_id'           =>  $_GET["product_id"],
            'item_name'         =>  $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'item_price'        =>  $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'item_quantity'     =>  $_POST["quantity"],
            'item_image'        =>  $_POST["hidden_image"],

        );
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;
    }     
}
```

Comment: you never increment the quantity. it seems you just copy the prev value to the new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the key of an item with `array_search` like this:

```
// look for 'item_id' with the value of $_GET["product_id"] inside of the cart
$itemIds = array_column( $_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id" );
$key = array_search( $_GET["product_id"], $itemIds );
```

and then you can easily update that item's quantity by doing something like this:

```
...
if (isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
{
    // look for 'item_id' with the value of $_GET["product_id"] inside of the cart
    $itemIds = array_column( $_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id" );
    $key = array_search( $_GET["product_id"], $itemIds );

    if ( $key === false )
    {
        $item_array = array(
            'item_id'           =>  $_GET["product_id"],
            'item_name'         =>  $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'item_price'        =>  $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'item_quantity'     =>  $_POST["quantity"],
            'item_image'        =>  $_POST["hidden_image"],

        );
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $item_array;
    }
    else
    {
        // if quantity is invalid do something, else
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$key]["item_quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thank You, it worked , can you please help me with quantity.

Comment: The second code snippet does that. Have you tried it?

Comment: No i mean on product page when user manually select the amount of quantity, it work for first time but when user insert more quantity then it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your program logic is correct, just update it to:

```
$count++;
$_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
```